# event.PreventDefault doesnt work until end of function

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox on which i am trying to send an ajax request based on its position. It is true by default. I want to be able to click it, and get a dialog that asks me if I want to discard my changes,and this dialog depends on the fact that the checkbox is not yet false.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      alert(this.checked);
      if(checkEdited()){
      var result = confirm("Do you want to continue?");
      }
    });

 function checkEdited(){
     var checkbox = $("div.managerContent input[type='checkbox']");
     if(!checkbox.checked){
      return false;
    }
    else{
    //check other stuff
    }
   }
```

And everytime, I am getting `false` in the alert. In the browser, when I click the checkbox the check goes away, i get the alert, and then the check comes back.. checkEdited() is also used in other places

Everywhere I look to find how to stop a checkbox change event and assign it a value later just tells me to use .click and e.prenventDeafult()

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6y2LP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attempt to capture the event before the click is complete, you can do this with `mousedown` like so:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('mousedown',function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      alert(this.checked);
});
```

Here is a demo with a working example of capturing it before it changes

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/k88nN/)

Comment: thanks! that works great! I did however use the $.mousedown() function instead.